# why doesn't the clean method see field in forms?

Tags: python, django

I'm facing an issue with my forms in Django. I've created something like this:

```py
class EventForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = [
            "name",
            "start_date",
            "end_date"
         
        ]

    def clean(self):
        start_date = self.cleaned_data["start_date"]
        end_date = self.cleaned_data["end_date"]
        if start_date > end_date:
            raise ValidationError("Start Date cannot be great than End Date")
        elif start_date == end_date:
            raise ValidationError("The dates must be different.")

    def clean_start_date(self):
        start_date = self.cleaned_data["start_date"]
        if timezone.now() > start_date:
            raise ValidationError("The start date of the event must be after today.")
        return start_date
```

When I tried to test it, something weird is happening. So, when I tried to input a **start_date** that is after today, I get the following message:
start_date = self.cleaned_data["start_date"]
KeyError: 'start_date'
It looks like clean() doesn't see the start_date. But why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`clean` happens *after* custom `clean_<field_name>` methods. Your  `clean_start_date` raised  a ValidationError, so the value for `start_date` was rejected and not included in `cleaned_data`.

Here is the relevant Django code:

```py
    def full_clean(self):
        """
        Clean all of self.data and populate self._errors and self.cleaned_data.
        """
        self._errors = ErrorDict()
        if not self.is_bound:  # Stop further processing.
            return
        self.cleaned_data = {}
        # If the form is permitted to be empty, and none of the form data has
        # changed from the initial data, short circuit any validation.
        if self.empty_permitted and not self.has_changed():
            return

        self._clean_fields()  # <---  clean_start_date is called here
        self._clean_form()  # <--- clean is called in here
        self._post_clean()

    def _clean_fields(self):
        for name, bf in self._bound_items():
            field = bf.field
            value = bf.initial if field.disabled else bf.data
            try:
                if isinstance(field, FileField):
                    value = field.clean(value, bf.initial)
                else:
                    value = field.clean(value)
                self.cleaned_data[name] = value
                if hasattr(self, "clean_%s" % name):
                    value = getattr(self, "clean_%s" % name)()  # <--- your clean method raises a ValidationError
                    self.cleaned_data[name] = value
            except ValidationError as e:
                self.add_error(name, e) #  <--- except is triggered; 'start_date' never added to cleaned_data
```

Comment: Than you for clarifying that ;)

Answer (score 2):

You missing call **`cleaned_data = super().clean()`** in **`def clean(self):`** try with this code.

```
from django import forms
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Event

class EventForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = [
            "name",
            "start_date",
            "end_date"
        ]

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean() # add this
        start_date = cleaned_data.get("start_date")
        end_date = cleaned_data.get("end_date")

        if start_date and end_date:
            if start_date > end_date:
                raise ValidationError("Start Date cannot be greater than End Date")
            elif start_date == end_date:
                raise ValidationError("The dates must be different.")

    def clean_start_date(self):
        start_date = self.cleaned_data.get("start_date")
        if start_date and start_date <= timezone.now():
            raise ValidationError("The start date of the event must be after today.")
        return start_date
```

Comment: `ModelForm.clean` only returns a reference to `self.cleaned_data`, so it shouldn't matter. Still, it **is** important to call the super method, because the parent class might do other stuff in it (f.ex. [ModelForm sets an important flag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-clean-method)).